# Fileserver returning 404

Tags: go, gorilla, fileserver

What I really want to do is serve two directories as fileservers, `/assets` and `/web/public`.  For reference, here is my project structure:

```
/root
    /assets
    /web
        /public
        /src
        /templates
    main.go
```

When I run the server however, the `/public` routes return 404, while the assets are fine.  I've combed through the reference and through a bunch of tutorials, and everything I'm doing should be above the board.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // here is where i set up the file servers
    publicHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir(filepath.Join("web", "public")))
    r.PathPrefix("/pubic/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/pubic/", publicHandler))

    assetHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/assets/", assetHandler))

    r.HandleFunc("/", s.HandleHome())
    
    port := fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 5123)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, r)
}

func (s *Server) HandleHome() http.HandlerFunc {
    tpl, err := template.New("").ParseFiles("web/templates/index.tpl")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "oops", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `http.StripPrefix("/pubic/"` <---- did you mean "public" here instead of "pubic"?

Comment: I can't believe that was it.  Thank you kind stranger.